# Form not returning a value?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I am trying to make a form, called "disclaimer" return a value.

Here is the code for the main form that calls the "disclaimer" form:

```
Form disclaimerWindow = new disclaimer();
disclaimerWindow.ShowDialog();
Console.WriteLine(disclaimerWindow.agreed);
```

Here is the relevant code *inside* of the "disclaimer" form:

```
public bool agreed { get; set; }
private void disagreeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.agreed = false;
    this.Close();
}
```

However, the Main Form is giving me a syntax error that: *"Form does not contain a definition for 'agreed'."* What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
Form disclaimerWindow = new disclaimer();
```

to this:

```
disclaimer disclaimerWindow = new disclaimer();
```

**Some additional notes**

Try following the .NET naming conventions and name your form with *Pascal* notation. So the name of your form's class should `Disclaimer` (capital D). Also change the property so it can only be set from within the form like this:

```
public bool Agreed { get; private set; }
```

Now other forms can only read the property and they cannot set it.